# A highly "active" puzzle

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, steganography

Original puzzle below created by me.

[image: The puzzle.]

Hint 1:

> You need to extract number(s) from each square.

Hint 2:

> All the numbers share something in common.

Hint 3:

> Binary.

Hint 4:

> You need to extract exactly two numbers from each square.

Comment: This is incredibly similar to [this puzzle](http://happinessboard.com/2022puzzlehunt/puzzles_files/XXtomezasXX-StXtcXes.pdf) from Edric's 2022 Puzzle Hunt, which released just a few hours before - is this a coincidence?

Comment: Huh, interesting. Completely coincidental, but I might take a look at the other puzzle and see if it has a similar idea.

Answer (score 1):

Partial progress:

> These are Hitomezashi patterns. Each vertical line has two possible states; ditto for each horizontal line.

> `Top left:  0010100 horizontal, 1100000 vertical`
>  `Top right: 0001100 horizontal, 1100011 vertical`
>  `Mid left:  0000100 horizontal, 1100100 vertical`
>  `Mid right: 1111000 horizontal, 1101000 vertical`
>  `Bot left:  0100100 horizontal, 1100110 vertical`
>  `Bot right: 1010100 horizontal, 1100101 vertical`

> Any of these codes could be flipped or inverted from their intended readings. Seven bits make me think ASCII.

EDIT:

> The first one is not a true Hitomezashi pattern. The bottom row of horizontal lines does not work.

Comment: I don't know how to do the community post thing

Answer (score 0):

[Community wiki, feel free to edit.]

Here's how the six given grids overlay:

[image]

Comment: @bobble It's a community wiki post, which is The Thing To Do for potentially-helpful data gathering without confirmed progress.

Comment: Many more six-in-an-overlay than i guessed., and 3 clear double rows.  More to look, perhaps it's 7-bit ASCII.